# reading from a .csv file to find ALL the peaks and valleys of the x,y coordinates dataset in c#

Tags: c#

I need to return all the peaks and valleys from the data in the csv file.  I keep getting an exception when I run the program telling me the string isn't in correct format. I don't know what I'm writing incorrectly.  I'm passing the values into testX and testY and then comparing them in my while loop.  The while loop is where I'm getting the error when I convert testY to a double.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApp6
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        double firstY = 0.0;

        string testX;
        string testY;

        string[] xpoint = new string[5000];
        string[] ypoint = new string[5000];

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"D:\data.csv"))
            {
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string line = reader.ReadLine();
                    var values = line.Split(',');

                    testX = values[0];
                    testY = values[1];

                    while (Convert.ToDouble(testY) <= firstY)
                    {
                        firstY = Convert.ToDouble(testY);

                        if (firstY == Convert.ToDouble(testY))
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (Convert.ToDouble(testY) > firstY)
                    {
                        listBox1.Items.Add(Convert.ToDouble(testX) + "," + firstY);
                    }

                    while (Convert.ToDouble(testY) >= firstY)
                    {
                        firstY = Convert.ToDouble(testY);

                        if (firstY == Convert.ToDouble(testY))
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (Convert.ToDouble(testY) < firstY)
                    {
                        listBox2.Items.Add(Convert.ToDouble(testX) + "," + firstY);
                    }

                    Convert.ToString(testX);
                    Convert.ToString(testY);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try printing `testY` to see what it is? Also, a couple of lines from your `csv` would be useful.

Comment: Yes, I have.  The streamreader is gathering the data and would pass it if I didn't convert it to a double.  I could display the the information in a listbox; but I've tried that. Then I'm having the issue not being able to use and compare the data without hardcoding the index of the points I'm comparing.

Comment: Post what the stackdump with the exact error, and what your printed before the error occurred, maybe it will help see what the problem is.

Comment: Do you have any blank lines in the file.  The error is due to the Convert.ToDouble() no finding a number to parse.

Comment: Those `while(Convert.ToDouble)` loops look dubious to me... you never introduce any new information into these loops.

Comment: This is the error I'm getting:  System.FormatException
  HResult=0x80131537
  Message=Input string was not in a correct format.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Number.ParseDouble(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
   at System.Convert.ToDouble(String value)
   at WindowsFormsApp6.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)